# How to override type() java interface method in a scala class

Tags: java, scala, reserved-words

I have a java interface with a method declared like this `String type();`. I want to implement it in a scala class, so I would like to write:

```
override def type = { ... }
```

But apparently its a reserved keyword in scala, so the compiler is complaining:

```
 identifier expected but 'type' found.
```

How is it possible to implement it? Is there a solution without having to change the Java interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use backticks to overcome the issue of reserved words:

```
override def `type` = { ... }
```

See: [Scala Interoperability FAQs](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Interoperability+FAQs)